# Invalid transfer on left side. (line 1, "Tests" file)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script that if the value written in cells L1, L2 and L3 is "Ok" then the script saves the spreadsheet to PDF if any of these three cells is written anything other than "Ok" the script should stop, should not continue and save the PDF.

```
function Test() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Squads'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('Squads!W17').activate();

  if ('Gerais!L1'="Ok"){
  spreadsheet.getRange('Gerais!M1').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Aprovado');
  }
  if ('Gerais!L2'="Ok"){
  spreadsheet.getRange('Gerais!M2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Aprovado');
  }
  if ('Gerais!L3'="Ok"){
  spreadsheet.getRange('Gerais!M3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().setValue('Aprovado');
  }

}
```

When I try to save to this script, the message: Invalid transfer appears on the left side. (line 1, "Tests" file)

What I want is that simply if cells L1, L2 and L3 are spelled "Ok" in them, the script goes to the next step and saves the spreadsheet in PDF.

The PDF Script I did not include here so as not to extend the size of the question. But it is obviously below the IF's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had one thing wrong:

For example `if('Gerais!L1'="Ok")` is an assignment not a comparison.  It should be written as `if(Gerais!L1'=="Ok")`

Also when using the macro tool, it tends to use a lot of activates and in general they are not necessary in scripts and just take up extra time and space.  Try to remove them unless you feel that they are absolutely necessary..

As for the rest of the code try this:

getValues() versus getValue() won't make that much difference here but in loops commands it can make a huge difference.

```
function Test() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Gerais');
  var rg=sh.getRange("L1:L3");
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  if (vA[0][0]=="Ok"){
    sh.getRange('M1').setValue('Aprovado');
  }
  if (vA[1][0]=="Ok"){
    sh.getRange('M2').setValue('Aprovado');
  }
  if (vA[2][0]=="Ok"){
    sh.getRange('M3').setValue('Aprovado');
  }
}
```

The value of putting data in rows or columns that are easy to retrieve with getValues() will become more useful to you as you improve your coding in the future and you will find it to be a very useful way of getting access to your data.

[Best Practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices)

Answer to additional question:

```
if(vA[][0]=="Ok" && vA[1][0]=="Ok" && vA[2][0]=="Ok") {
  //continue to pdf
}else{
  //take another path
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Now a final question, my idea is that if L1, or L2 or L3 has a value other than "Ok", the script should not continue and create the spreadsheet saved in PDF ... How could I do this? For example, giving an error that stops script continuation could be an option. Or some code that stops the script if any of the cells is not spelled "Ok". Could you help me with that?

Comment: Is that where the `Squads` spreadsheet comes into the question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the value of a cell, you need to call getRange() and getValue() or getValues().

For example:

```
var data = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Gerais').getRange('L1:L3').getValues();
if (data[0][0] == 'OK') { // data[0][0] is L1
  // do something fun
}
if (data[1][0] == 'OK') { // data[1][0] is L2
  // do something fun
}
// etc.
```